# When submitting form, Submitter is not Sender. How to make submitter equal to sender?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, form-submit, active-users

I am a bit lost here.

My script intends to send an Email and create calender entries when submitting a form. 
This works perfectly fine. However, the Email is always sent from my account. But eventually, I want different users in my company to use this script and each submitter needs to be the according sender of the email sent out. Otherwise I will always receive all replies, this won't be fun!!

I am sure this works somehow, but how?

Any ideas or recommendations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behavior : when a script sends an email it is sent by the author of the script (in this case : you). That's mainly to respect privacy rules since users filling a form are not asked to grant access to their email , neither to authorize for sending emails in their name.

There are 2 possible solutions :

1. Use the optional `replyTo` parameter in the [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app.html#sendEmail%28String,String,String,String%29) line (you will always be the sender but when people reply using the 'reply' button the mail will be sent to that address instead of yours.(*I assumed you know the submitter's email adress either by asking him in the form or retrieving it automatically if you work in the context of a domain account*)
2. build your form using [UiApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/ui-service) or [HTMLService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) as a standalone webapp that will be executed as "[the user executing the app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps#deploying)" and ask each user for explicit authorization to send email using their account".  But that will be a bit more complex to setup compared with normal Google Forms Service.

Knowing that it's up to you to choose the better approach.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response,

I just wondered, the GAS got the option to "Deploying Your Script as a Web App" - this doesn't appear very complicated at first, is it?

Comment: It all depends what one consider as "complicated" it depends also on how complex is your form... ;-) in this option you'll have to build the entire form in a script. (btw, what about "accepting" the answer above ?)

Comment: Replyto works fine! The only disadvantage I see is that my email will be shown always. This might create confusion when external people receive the email. I might have to create an Alias to get around this challenge.

Comment: What I do personally is creating a group with an address like 'mailing@myDomain.com" as a reply adress, in this group I put whoever wants or needs to be , depending on the circumstances... sometimes I'm in, sometimes not if I'm not interested. This solution works pretty well.

Comment: To add to that, you can use the `name` key in the `options` of the MailApp function that takes the optional parameter. Then it would *look* like it came from a *unique* sender (whoever you want the name to be), and the `replyTo` would still be the desired email address. In total, with those two parameters combined, it looks like it came from a specific person and will reply to that specific person, even though it was sent from your account.